# How to export Python printed output to txt file at the end of code

Tags: python

I have several thousand lines of code that all ultimately results in a few strings being printed using `print()` calls. Is there a way to, at the bottom of my code, export everything that has been printed to a text file?

Comment: Not after the `print()` statements have already happened, no.  You can change the `print()` statements so they write to a file instead of to the screen, or you can redirect the output of the program to a file when you run it.

Answer (score 2):

This will help.

```
python main.py > output.txt
```

The operator `>` redirects the output of `main.py` from `stdout` to the regular file `output.txt`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want your output to be written immediately without delay, you can add `-u` parametre. The command becomes `python -u main.py > output.txt`. `-u` disables buffer in Python output, which is default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with redirection in your shell or reopening `sys.stdout`. Here are both ways:

1. Reopen `sys.stdout`:

At the beginning of your code, you can use this code:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('logfile', 'w')

# ... rest of your program ...
```

and everything printed to standard output (including `print()` calls) will be written to `logfile`. This method will always work.

2. Redirection in your shell:

This is my preferred method if you're running the script from the command line every time. In some niche cases, this won't work (ie: the script is being run by some other program), but it will work for 90% of cases. You can simply run your original script like this:

```
python myFile.py > logfile
```

and everything will be written to `logfile`. If for some reason this doesn't work for you, use method #1.